# template virtual function

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

Here is some code:

```
class IWorker {
public:
    virtual void Do(int x) const = 0;
};

class TSomeWorker : public IWorker {
    void Do(int x) const {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Now, imagine that we need to refactor it in such way that function Do should become template (int changes into some T). I know that C++ does not allow to create template virtual functions. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648430/designing-hiearchical-classes-with-template-function/7648621#7648621

Comment: and another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968023/c-virtual-template-method

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your specific needs. But according to what you posted I would suggest:

```
template<typename T>
class IWorker {
public:
    virtual void Do(T x) const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class TSomeWorker : public IWorker<T> {
    void Do(T x) const {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: The problem here is that when I use class IWorker in some other classes I have to make them to be templates too. But they're not. The nature of the class says that only the funciton Do is templated :)

Comment: A generalized solution to this is described in the answers @jpalecek linked to. If you want a more specific solution to your problem, you have to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to mix static polymorphism (templates) and run-time polymorphism (virtual functions), but those are orthogonal. In such case, you need to cast :

```
class IWorker {
public:
    virtual void Do(void* x) const = 0;
};

template< typename T >
class TSomeWorker : public IWorker {
    void Do(void* x) const {
        T* realX = reinterpret_cast< T* >( x );
        // ...
    }
};
```